# how to run an oracle script using php

Tags: php, oracle

I've started a project where the user can either connect to a mySQL database or an oracle database. I got the mySQL part down but oracle is being a bit difficult. Standard queries work such as `SELECT * FROM author`, but when I try to load a script in order to create the schema I get invalid operation errors. I've tried using 'START' and '@' in various ways but to no avail. These commands work in the command line but not in php. I've tried the following:

```
else if($databaseType == "Oracle")
{
$c = oci_connect($username, $password, $server);
     if (!$c) {
       echo "Unable to connect: " . var_dump( oci_error() );
       die();
     }


    // Delete previous schema
    $s = oci_parse($c, "@/oracle/dropall");
    oci_execute($s, OCI_DEFAULT);

    // Create schema
    $s = oci_parse($c, "@/oracle/oracle");
    oci_execute($s, OCI_DEFAULT);

    // Create first trigger
    $s = oci_parse($c, "@/oracle/oracle_trigger1");
    oci_execute($s, OCI_DEFAULT);

    // Create second trigger
    $s = oci_parse($c, "@/oracle/oracle_trigger2");
    oci_execute($s, OCI_DEFAULT);

    // Populate the database
    $s = oci_parse($c, "@/oracle/oracle_populate");
    oci_execute($s, OCI_DEFAULT);


    // Commit to save changes...
    oci_commit($c);

    // Logoff from Oracle...
    oci_free_statement($s);
    oci_close($c);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OCI_PARSE**

> resource oci_parse ( resource $connection , string $sql_text )

It expecting a SQL statement instead of file name.

You want to try:

```
 $s = oci_parse($c, file_get_contents('/oracle/dropall'));
```